# SharePoint 2013: nativehr0x80070002ativehrnativestackativestack error when documents are uploaded to a document library

Tags: visual-studio

I am frequently experiencing an error in my SharePoint 2013 on premise environment when users try to upload a document to a document library. When a user uploads a document, the person is asked to fill out two fields (both are lookups to values in external lists). Afterward, the workflow should send the document to a 'To Be Approved' folder. However, this is not happening for 'some' documents so they get stuck. Not every document is failing to move. A developer created a custom Visual Studio workflow so the solution is deployed as a .WSP to the farm. I do not have access to the source code. The error 'nativehr0x80070002ativehrnativestackativestack' is logged in a custom list called 'Logs' in SharePoint. However, I obtained the ULS logs for that time and I have added that below. The build information is Windows Server 2012 R2 (Build 9600​) with SharePoint 2013 v.15.0.4727.1000​​​​​​. Any help / guidance is much appreciated. Further, how can one see the source code in the .WSP file.

Note: Below, I have changed the user's staff id to 'user id' and I have re-named the .pdf file.

ULS Log:
ttidLogWssCellStgConcise [Url: Incoming Documents/test123.pdf][User: i:0#.w|user id (NonCobaltOriginated)][StreamSizes: Request=0 bytes, Response=0 bytes][TotalRequestTime: 16msec][PartitionID: Default][Request: PutChanges **FFU Pri=0 Result=Success][cbOld=0][cbNew=111464][cLR:0][MD:0=AutoGenerated.OOF.No.NoOtherUsers.FutureOpen.Recently.DocumentIsActive.Content.Wired.None.Normal][cBCQ=0][cbCQ=0][cBRB=0][cbRB=0][cbREB=0][cBHBW=4][cbHBW=113262][cbHBEW=257280][cBHBDel=0][Mngd]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the root cause of your issue so only answer partially about how to get the source code.

1. Backup wsp solution.

   $farm = Get-SpFarm
   $file = $farm.Solutions.Item(“yourSOlutionName.wsp”).SolutionFile
   $file.SaveAs(“C:\Temp\yourSOlutionName.wsp”)
2. Rename the wsp file to .cab extension (wsp is just a compressed file)
3. Now you should have access to the wsp files.
4. To read dll you will need some kind of decompiler to look into the file 
   few examples you will find in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706377/how-do-you-extract-classes-source-code-from-a-dll-file

Comment: Thanks Marek for your suggestions. I tried JetBrains dotPeek... do these tools give you 100% of the code?

Comment: I use same one, usually it does have all code but depending on the way it was compiled you will loose the comment lines.